# How to integrate Chat-Bot in React-Native

Tags: react-native, sap-conversational-ai

I'm using React-Native for the development of Mobile App. Now I'm having a requirement to implement a chat-bot in my React-Native Mobile App.

I heard about Recast.AI NLP Based Platform, but I got stuck. How to integrate Recast.AI in React Native technology? What's the possible solutions for that?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 completely separate parts of software needed to implement Chat Bots in React-Native:

1. Messaging platform
2. Chat Bot engine

1) Regarding Messaging Platform - you need some solution which will provide your React-Native app the messaging capabilities. So you will have 2 types of users: normal real users and Chat bots users. Normal users will send messages using your React-Native app and Chat Bots will be programmable users with some automatic responses.

I used ConnectyCube in some of my projects, they have the React Native SDK to develop apps with messaging functionality:

- 1-1 messaging
- Group messaging
- Sent/Delivered/Read statuses
- 'Is typing' statuses
- File attachments
- Push notifications to offline users
- Contact list
- Block list

React Native SDK - Getting Started: https://developers.connectycube.com/js/react-native

Chat functionality - Getting Started https://developers.connectycube.com/js/messaging

2) Regarding Chat Bot engine - I used [RiveScript](http://%20https://www.rivescript.com/) in some of my projects in it's awesome. It gives you a ***.rive** [file](https://www.rivescript.com/docs/tutorial#first-steps) where you can program all your questions/answers, as many scenarios as you could imagine.